# Control-D not recognized by MINGW64 on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, controls, mingw-w64

When trying the OpenFaaS workshop (https://github.com/openfaas/workshop/blob/master/lab2.md) i stumbled upon a problem with the shell on windows:

I am running OpenFaaS using the Docker Toolbox for Windows and therefore use the Docker Quickstart Terminal as a shell which is based on MINGW64. Now one of the sample functions is implemented the way that you can call `faas-cli invoke markdown` and then type in some text. It displays `Reading from STDIN - hit (Control + D) to stop.` However, after typing in some Text and pressing **Control+D**, it is not recognized, but `^D` is printed in the console.

I guess this is some issue with running MINGW64 on Windows, any ideas how to actually send the End-of-Transmission-Character?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the answer myself in a different context. On some systems **Control+Z** has to be used. So in my case <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> plus <kbd>Enter</kbd> finished the write to STDIN.

Comment: Didn't work for me in mingw64's python

Comment: Try using command `winpty python ... ` winpty comes with mingw64.